# How do I avoid chains of method calls like @invoice.customer.address.street etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have some models and have views code that look like the following

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

This code shows a simple invoice structure, with a customer who has a single address.
The view code to display the address lines for the invoice would be as follows:

```
<%= @invoice.customer.name %>
<%= @invoice.customer.address.street %>
<%= @invoice.customer.address.city %>,
<%= @invoice.customer.address.state %>
<%= @invoice.customer.address.zip_code %>
```

above view code is not ideal. For proper encapsulation, the
invoice should not reach across the customer object to the street attribute of the
address object. Because if, for example, in the future your application were to change
so that a customer has both a billing address and a shipping address, every place in
your code that reached across these objects to retrieve the street would break and
would need to change. How can I avoid this problem ?

Comment: Partials and/or delegates and/or helper methods.

Comment: can you give me some example how can i do this @DaveNewton

Comment: Please change the title of your question.  "How can I solve/do this?" says nothing of the problem and will not help anyone searching in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simples solution would be the customer have a method that will return its main address, like:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def main_address
    self.address
  end
end
```

If you access its address only by this method, when it has more than one address it is necessary just change the `main_address` method to do whatever you want to.

**Edit 1:**

Another option would be use the [delegate](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb) as suggested by @soundar

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  delegate :address, :to => :customer
end
```

Comment: should I create 10 different method (like def main_address and others) If in my table have 10 column? if yes then to much coding in my model.

Comment: I don't believe you'll have to do with all the properties, since name and other properties are not supposed to change. The address may be multiple and may change, you have to do your evaluate whether it should apply or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate feature to reduce of sequence of function calls.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  delegate :address, :to => :customer
end

<%= @invoice.customer.name %>
<%= @invoice.address.street %>
<%= @invoice.address.city %>,
<%= @invoice.address.state %>
<%= @invoice.address.zip_code %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem just describe, it's important to follow the `Law of Demeter`, also known as the `Principle of Least Knowledge`.

To follow the Law of Demeter, you could rewrite the code above as follows:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  has_many :invoices

  def street
    address.street
  end

  def city
    address.city
  end

  def state
    address.state
  end

end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  def customer_name
    customer.name
  end

  def customer_street
    customer.street
  end

  def customer_state
    customer.state
  end
end
```

And you could change the view code to the following:

```
<%= @invoice.customer_name %>
<%= @invoice.customer_street %>
<%= @invoice.customer_city %>
<%= @invoice.customer_state %>
```

In above code, public interface on **Invoice** has been polluted by methods that arguably have nothing to do with the rest of your interface for invoices. This is a general disadvantage of Law of Demeter, and it it not particularly specific to Ruby on Rails.

Now, The method is the class-level `delegate` method. This method provides a shortcut for indicating that one or more methods that will be created on your object are actually provided by a related object. Using this delegate method, you can rewrite your example like this:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  has_many :invoices

  delegate :street, :city, :state, :to => :address
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  delegate :name, :street, :city, :state, :to => :customer, :prefix => true
end
```

In this situation, you don't have to change your view code, the methods are exposed just as they were before:

```
<%= @invoice.customer_name %>
<%= @invoice.customer_street %>
<%= @invoice.customer_city %>
<%= @invoice.customer_state %>
```